# RSpec explicitly tagged cases failing from NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm currently using `rspec-core-3.1.7` with a rails application I've inherited. It seems like the previous owners made a lot of progress with their testing suite, but I can't seem to get it working properly. My `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` are fresh from a `rails generate rspec:install`, with some minor tweaks.

The way the tests are set-up looks as follows:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe FooController, :type => :routing do
  ...
```

and here was the relevant error message:

```
athan@spacerobot:~/website$ rake spec:routing
/home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby -I/home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib:/home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.1.2/lib /home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec --pattern ./spec/routing/\*\*/\*_spec.rb
/home/athan/website/spec/routing/foo_routing_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant FooController (NameError)
    from /home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
...
```

But for some reason, I can't get `rspec` to find `FooController` before it throws the NameError. Is it a common convention to... pretend these classes exist, when describing RSpec tests? Where would they come from...? How should I properly define test descriptions?

Comment: I'm a little confused, does FooController actually exist?

Comment: @trueinViso I think it should... should it just be a `class FooController...` definition somewhere? Is there usually a convention for where these data types should be declared?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with how rails uses rspec, but I do use rspec quite a bit for my test suites. I am suspecting that you need to add a require for the FooController into either the spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb.  In my case, I require all of my test framework components in the spec_helper.rb so that they are available for all the tests to use.  Hope that helps.